# reading excel using oledb replace special characters with?

Tags: c#, oledb

I Have A problem that im reading an Excel file using oledb and Convert that into DataTable so whenever i fetch data from Excel that replace Some Special characters with like 'Ó' replaces with '?' But i want that characters remains as it is

my Code for Reading Data from Excel file

```
private DataSet getData(string Path)
    {
        string fileName = Path;
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source="+fileName+";ExtendedProperties="+"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;";
        OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [SHEET1$]", con);
        DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
        cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);

        con.Close();
        return  excelDataSet;
    }
```

---

*Input               ->  RamÓn y Cajal,
*Actual Output       ->  Ram?n y Cajal,
*Expected Output     ->  RamÓn y Cajal,

I think its because of Character encoding Format .
Please help me

Comment: Consider adding "Locale Identifier=nnnn;" (where nnnn is 32 bit integer identifying your table's locale) to the connection string you use.